# Connecting from WAN to LAN

Tags: ip, tcp

I'm developing an app for my family that uses sockets to comunicate between devices in LAN or WAN. As IP addresses change constantly I am planning an FTP server for address book and TCP/IP for communication.

My problem:
Connecting from WAN to LAN. I think the router should be set to allow a connection from outside to a port on the LAN. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most home NA[P]T gateway routers let you specify a "port mapping", "port forwarding" rule, or sometimes it's even called a "virtual server", where connections from the WAN, to a certain TCP or UDP port on the router's WAN IP address, are forwarded to a LAN private IP address and port where the service really resides.

In the example of FTP, port 21/TCP is usually used for incoming control connections, so you would want to enter a port mapping in your router to forward port 21/TCP from your router's WAN address, to the LAN private IP address and port where you're running an FTP server (e.g. 192.168.1.2:21).

So, when out on the WAN, you'd tell your FTP client to connect to your router's WAN IP address, and you'd actually end up getting connected to your FTP server which is actually on a different address behind the NAT.

Beware that FTP is an extra tricky protocol to get working behind a NAT. It helps if your NAT gateway has FTP "ALG" (Application-Layer Gateway) code that knows how to deal with an FTP server behind the NAT. You see, when an FTP client is behind a NAT, using FTP Passive (PASV) mode can make FTP work through the NAT. But when the FTP ***server*** is behind the NAT, even with the necessary port mapping for 21/TCP, passive mode breaks, whereas active mode would have worked. If the FTP client is behind one NAT and the FTP server is behind another NAT, you definitely need an FTP ALG in one or both NATs.